# Shortcut to insert from type hint in Intellij Rust?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-rust

IntelliJ IDEA gives useful type hints. Is there a shortcut to insert them into the source code?

[image]

Comment: `Vec<impl Future<...>>` is inlay hint, it should not be inserted to the source code. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/inlay-hints.html

Other hints could be inserted via Enter and Tab

Answer (score 1):

Press Alt+Enter and select "Specify type explicitly".

[image]

Comment: This solution is useful for other languages, such as Kotlin, where type hinting is supported.  Thanks, @ozkriff